# VBA Copy and paste entire row if cell matches list of IDs, but do not paste if list contains blank cell or cell with ""

Tags: excel, list, row, copy-paste

I have what I thought would be a simple script, but I have some some strange results.

Goal: Identify specific IDs in a *SOURCE* sheet using a list of IDs on a *Translator* Sheet. When found, copy the entire row to and *OUTPUT* sheet.

The output has strange results that I can't figure out.

- Returns all results instead of the limited list. AND results are in weird groupings. (First result is on row 21 and only has 9 rows of data, the next group has 90 rows of data, starting on row 210, then blank rows, then 900 rows of data, etc.
- Results do not start in row 2.

Full code is below attempts:

Attempts:

1. I first searched the *SOURCE* sheet based on one ID that was hard coded as a simple test and it worked. but when I changed the code to search a range (z21:z), two things happened: 1, it returns everything in the Source file in multiples of 9 as stated above, AND as you can imagine, the time to complete skyrocketed from seconds to minutes. I think I missed a add'l section of code to identify the range??

Old Code:

```
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = Worksheets("D62D627EB404207DE053D71C880A3E05") Then
xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Output").Range("A2" & J + 1)
J = J + 1
End If
```

New code:

```
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = Worksheets("Translator").Range("z21:z" & I)** Then
xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Output").Range("A2" & J + 1)
J = J + 1
End If
```

- 1a. I believe one issue is that the Translator list has duplicates. Second, it is searching the entire column Z. Second issue may be that The list in *Translator* is generated via a formula in column Z, thus if the formula is false, it will insert a "" into the cell. I seek the code to NOT paste those rows where the cell content is either a "" or is a true blank cell. Reason: The "" will cause issues when we try to load the Output file into a downstream system because it is not a true blank cell.

2. Results in wrong location: When the script is complete, my first result does not start on Row 2 as expected. I thought the clear contents would fix this, but maybe a different clear function is required? or the clear function is in the wrong place?  Below screenshot shows how it should show up. It is in the same columns but doesn't start until row 21.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw19G.png)
3. Slow code: I have a command that copies and pastes of the first row from *SOURCE* to *OUTPUT*. My code is cumbersome. There has to be an easier way. I am doing this copy and paste just in case the source file adds new columns in the future.

> ```
> Worksheets("Output").Cells.ClearContents
>  Sheets("SOURCE").Select
>  Rows("1:1").Select
>  Selection.Copy
>  Sheets("Output").Select
>  Rows("1:1").Select
>  ActiveSheet.Paste
> ```

Thank you for all your help.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MoveRowBasedOnCellValuefromlist()
'Updated by xxx 2023.01.18
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim K As Long
I = Worksheets("SOURCE").UsedRange.Rows.Count
J = Worksheets("Output").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If J = 1 Then
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Output").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
End If   
Worksheets("Output").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("SOURCE").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
 Selection.Copy
Sheets("Output").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Set xRg = Worksheets("SOURCE").Range("B2:B" & I)
On Error Resume Next
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'NOTE - There are duplicates in the Translator list. I only want it to paste the first instance.
'Otherwise, I need to create an =Unique() formula and that seems like unnecessary work.
 For K = 1 To xRg.Count
 If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = Worksheets("Translator").Range("z21:z" & I) Then
xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Output").Range("A2" & J + 1)
  J = J + 1
 End If
 Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your code here.

Comment: Thanks Tim. When I highlighted the entire code and hit ctrl K, I kept getting an  error where it would not let me submit, so I ended hitting Ctrl K for every line. I'll be more careful next time. Thanks!

Comment: `Destination:=Worksheets("Output").Range("A2" & J + 1)` if J =10 then you're copying to A211

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out - using Match as a fast way to check if a value is contained in your lookup list.

```vb
Sub MoveRowBasedOnCellValuefromlist()
    Dim c As Range, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim cDest As Range, wsTrans As Worksheet, rngList As Range
   
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'for example
    Set wsSrc = wb.Worksheets("SOURCE")
    Set wsOut = wb.Worksheets("Output")
    
    Set wsTrans = wb.Worksheets("Translator")
    Set rngList = wsTrans.Range("Z21:Z" & wsTrans.Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    ClearSheet wsOut
    wsSrc.Rows(1).Copy wsOut.Rows(1)
    Set cDest = wsOut.Range("A2")  'first paste destination
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In wsSrc.Range("B2:B" & wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rngList, 0)) Then 'any match in lookup list?
            c.EntireRow.Copy cDest
            Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1) 'next paste row
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'clear a worksheet
Sub ClearSheet(ws As Worksheet)
    With ws.Cells
        .ClearContents
        .ClearFormats
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. This works great. I will test in detail. With that said, Can you help me understand the Sub clearsheet section at the bottom.  In the middle of the main body of the code you have,  ClearSheet wsOut. This wipes wsOut. that makes sense. But Is this related to/ pulling from the 'clear a worksheet section at the bottom? or idid you add that just for reference if I need to clear a sheet?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a good practice to break out re-usable single-purpose blocks of code into separate methods which you can then call from your main code, instead of having your main method do everything.  This makes your code more re-usable, and allows you to focus on the core logic instead of "housekeeping" tasks.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.  Just so I understand the system steps. When the system gets to the line of code "ClearSheet wsOut", it identifies Clearsheet as a sub task (because nothing is infront of it such as dim, set, etc.) and goes looking for a sub code named Clearsheet. When found, it will execute that block of code on the identified worksheet "wsOut". Is that accurate? Thank you for the education! This is great.

Comment: Yes that's a good summary of calling out to another method (Sub/Function/etc) and passing in an argument.